# GDB not showing full stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug multithreaded OpenGL program in Eclipse CDT to locate source of random crashes and sometimes I have random SIGTRAP and SIGSEGV signals whithout full stack like this stack:

[image: stack]

What should I do to see full stack in debugger and what can be source of those signals?
I am compiling with `-g3` and `-ggdb` flags on MinGW and Windows x64.

EDIT:
I ran GDB from console and result is similar:

```
#0  0x00007ffee8c230a2 in ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x00007ffee8c08d36 in ntdll!RtlZeroHeap () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00007ffee8bde1b7 in ntdll!memset () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x00007ffee8c21f34 in ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x00007ffee8bdb24f in ntdll!memset () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x00007ffee8b654a8 in ntdll!RtlFreeHeap () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00007ffee6fc1cb3 in msvcrt!_setjmp () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#7  0x0000000006ecfd90 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: I don't know, but SIGSEGV is illegal memory access - you access memory that you have no rights to and SIGTRAP is usually breakpoint  (or watchpoint). If it's not set by debugger, it could be assert.

Comment: It could be your code has already gone off the deep end and GDB can't unwind the stack because it is actually corrupted, as GDB suggests. It looks suspicious to me that _setjmp is calling RtlFreeHeap, but of course it _could_ be?